# Send json data to remote server for authentication

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, windows-phone-8, json.net

I want to post authentication details to a remote server, sending username, database name and password. My server is running on Ubuntu. But i get error  Invalid JSON data: ''
"POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 -
I am new to working on this platform, help me with where i am doing it wrong. Below is my code:

```
private void SendDataButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string url = "http://200.84.100.211:9875";
    string call = url + "/web/session/authenticate";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(call) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(SendData), request);
}

void SendData(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
    Stream postStream = myRequest.EndGetRequestStream(callbackResult);
    string postData = "{'db':'demo_shruti','login':'admin','password':'admin'}";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    postStream.Close();
    myRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), myRequest); 
}

void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);
    string responseString = "";
    Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
    responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
    streamResponse.Close();
    reader.Close();
    response.Close();
    string result = responseString; 
}
```

Comment: Single quotes are not valid in JSON. Consider using double quotes

Comment: Off-topic, but should you really be sending security-sensitive info across the network without SSL/TLS?

Comment: @LukeH I am just trying the code for initial connection purpose, once this issue is solved i will set the security standards also.